# AWS-Lamda in private subnet can access DynamoDB triggers without VPC-Endpoint Or Nat Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc

I have created a VPC with Private and Public Subnet .Now in one of the private subnet I created a Lambda Function with Dynamo DB Tigger's with DynamoDB full access Permission ,CloudWatch Permission Ec2 Network Interface permission. DynamoDB streams are enable .But I did not create any VPC endpoint for DynamoDB still My function is working .I am not sure how it is working as DynamoDB is in Private subnet with no NAT gate and VPC endpoint .Please help

Comment: "DynamoDB is in Private subnet " - dynamodb can't be in a VPC. Can you clarify what do you mean?

Comment: Why did you attach the Lambda function to the VPC? If you only wish to access AWS services, then do _not_ attach it to a VPC. This will provide Internet access to the function.

Comment: What's the route table of your private subnet?

Comment: @MarcinDynamoDB is not in VPC .Lamda Function is in side VPC with private subnet .So when Lamda is inside VPC with private subnet how it can access DynamoDB event without VPC endpoint

Comment: @jellycsc Rotue table for private subnet dont have any VPC endpoint or NAT gateway or InternetGateway .Please let me know if you want me to paste my screenshot of route table for private subnet.